speedtest cli with cron and date
I would like a cron job running every hour for speedtest cli and to log it to csv file with time and date (https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli). So I can run it this way
0 * * * * speedtest -p no -f csv >> /home/almalinux/speedtest.csv

how can I inject the "date" command output as the first column (entry) for each speedtest ?
Based on the Answer below. Working command is this.
0 * * * * (printf "\%s," "$(date)"; speedtest -p no -f csv) >> /home/almalinux/speedtest.csv


You may find the ts command helpful - see for example how to add timestamp to stdout and stderr from a crontab job?

The simplest way I know is like this:
0 * * * * (printf "%s," "$(date)";speedtest -p no -f csv) >> /home/almalinux/speedtest.csv

The printf will print date as string, followed by , (if this is your delimiter) and the the result of speedtest
Will be good practice to escape % for the printf become:
printf "\%s," "$(date)"


perfect exactly what I need. Thanks. Delimiter is "," I will update the post

sorry I take this back. It runs directly from the terminal buy not from CRON for some reason

@ArkadiuszRycyk, what do you see in log?

How do I check the log ?

line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"')

%s was throwing it off. I had to escape the % wit %

@ArkadiuszRycyk, thank you will update my answer

cron interprets its command with sh, so the easy way is:
In crontab

0 * * * * /home/almalinux/bin/myscript

  
And in `$HOME/bin/myscript`:

#!/bin/bash
(printf "%s," "$(date)";speedtest -p no -f csv) >> /home/almalinux/speedtest.csv
exit 0


can't you format properly gee...
